# Do you have to escape back slashes or do any special encoding with Rs Digest function within the Alteryx R tool

Tags: r, sha, revolution-r, alteryx

I'm using the Alteryx R tool to do some sha256 hash calculations, but I'm running into trouble with one of my inputs.  I'm trying to produce the sha256 hash for the following input:

```
POST\n/\n\ncontent_type:\nhost:dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-date:20150707T201951Z\nx-amz-target:DynamoDB_20120810.CreateTable\n\ncontent_type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target\n09a8bcdeea1d20631f887235820bbff0a614679080a2e74a89ceb1a1bcc71b44
```

My r function is:

```
 digest('POST\n/\n\ncontent_type:\nhost:dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-date:20150707T201951Z\nx-amz-target:DynamoDB_20120810.CreateTable\n\ncontent_type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target\n09a8bcdeea1d20631f887235820bbff0a614679080a2e74a89ceb1a1bcc71b44', algo='sha256', serialize = FALSE)
```

and the hash produced by R is:

```
7fe2c3fc70134481217952f27bb5f4af95193645903ba3a6d4d7ad45c3adade1
```

This value is not correct.  The correct value is:

```
9a493c643eeb736decc195a8e0e84e08f45a00bdbc21feaafa94be5f0f299af0
```

You can see the correct value calculated below using Python;

[Calculated With Python](http://ideone.com/UFC1wR)

I've also calculated the correct value using the R command line tool.  This leads me to believe that Alteryx is somehow altering the input and as a result is producing the wrong output. Has anyone come across this or know a possible workaround.

My R tool script follows:

[image]

where c =

```
POST\n/\n\ncontent_type:\nhost:dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-date:20150707T201951Z\nx-amz-target:DynamoDB_20120810.CreateTable\n\ncontent_type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target\n09a8bcdeea1d20631f887235820bbff0a614679080a2e74a89ceb1a1bcc71b44
```

Comment: If I copy/paste your `digest()` command to R, i get the value that starts with "9a" just like the Python example. Can you double check your work? I cannot reproduce this error (using `digest_0.6.8`)

Comment: @MrFlick I actually did the same thing after I posted the question. The piece of the puzzle I neglected to include is that I'm using the Alteryx R tool to run the calculation.  I get the impression that Alteryx is somehow corrupting the input.  I'm going to EDIT my question. . thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you replace all `\` with `\\` in your input string (in regular R or Python), it will `digest` to the value starting with "7fe..." so this suggests that indeed, Alteryx is doing something like that in the hand-off to R.

A work-around would be to run it through the Alteryx base64 tool prior to the R tool, then have the R tool base 64 decode, something like:

```
library("digest")
library("caTools")
df <- as.data.frame(read.Alteryx("#1", mode="data.frame"))
df$out <- digest(base64decode(as.character(df$b64),what="character"), algo='sha256', serialize = FALSE)
write.Alteryx(df, 1)
```

While not ideal, it will give the correct output starting with "9a493..."